# BIP 32 Private keys to be imported into HSM

Tags: wallet, private-key, bip32-hd-wallets

Could someone explain to me how the import of private key in HSM works? Below is the information from the manual:

> Private Key Import/Export
>
> Private keys can be imported and exported
> with existing PKCS#11 functions. They can be imported and exported
> only if the HSM uses the key wrap model instead of cloning. Import a
> key by calling `C_Encrypt*()` on the serialized key followed by
> `C_UnwrapKey()`. Exporting keys by calling `C_WrapKey()` followed by `C_ Decrypt*()`. Use `C_WrapKey()` and `C_UnwrapKey()` to store keys off the
> HSM, or to move them between HSMs.

What key is used for the wrap?

Comment: I assume this is to do with Thales SafeNet Luna Hardware Security Module?

Comment: yes , it is the SafeNet Luna HSM